# Failed LockRect of IDirect3DSurface9

Tags: c++, directx, directx9

I have hooked Present method of the IDirect3DDevice9 interface, and I want to be able to start video capturing.

Taking a screenshoot like this work

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('O') & 1) {
pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((rect.right - rect.left),(rect.bottom - rect.top),D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,&back_buffer, NULL);
pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &back_buffer);
D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(L"C:\\screenshot.bmp", D3DXIFF_BMP, back_buffer, 0, NULL );

IDirect3DSurface9_Release(back_buffer);
```

}

I seem to fail to lock the surface with **0x8876086C(D3DERR_INVALIDCALL)**

```
HRESULT APIENTRY hook_Present(IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice, const RECT* pSourceRect,const RECT* pDestRect, HWND hDestWindowOverride,const RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion) {
IDirect3DSurface9*back_buffer;
D3DDEVICE_CREATION_PARAMETERS cparams;
RECT rect;
pDevice->GetCreationParameters(&cparams);
GetClientRect(cparams.hFocusWindow, &rect);
if (GetAsyncKeyState('R') & 1) {
    if(dx9Capturing == 0) {
        //Create the AVI file
        // etc code
        dx9Capturing = 1
    }
    else if(dx9Capturing == 1) dx9Capturing = 2; // stop capturing
}

if(dx9Capturing == 1) {
    // Capture the current frame
    pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((rect.right - rect.left),(rect.bottom - rect.top),D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,&back_buffer, NULL);
    pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &back_buffer);
    D3DLOCKED_RECT  lockedRect;
    if(FAILED(back_buffer->LockRect(&lockedRect,&rect,D3DLOCK_READONLY))) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed locking the back buffer!", "Error", MB_OK);
        return orig_Present(pDevice, pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<rect.bottom;i++)
        {
            memcpy((BYTE*)pBits+(rect.bottom-i-1)*rect.right*BITSPERPIXEL/8,(BYTE*)lockedRect.pBits+i*lockedRect.Pitch,rect.right*BITSPERPIXEL/8);
        }
    back_buffer->UnlockRect();
    pAviFile->AddNewFrame(rect.right,rect.bottom,pBits);
}

return orig_Present(pDevice, pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion);
```

}

Hooking Reset and I still have the same problem

```
HRESULT APIENTRY hook_Reset (IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice,D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS* pPresentationParameters) {
HRESULT hr;
if(pFont) {
    pFont->Release();
}

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; 
D3DDISPLAYMODE d3ddm;
direct->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &d3ddm );
ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = true;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = d3ddm.Format;
    d3dpp.Flags =  D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;
hr =  orig_Reset(pDevice, &d3dpp);
return hr;
```

}

Comment: Please visit [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to have your accounts merged. This will allow you to edit the post and post comments under the question and the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The device needs to be created with [D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172586(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Set this flag if the application requires the ability to lock the back buffer directly. Note that back buffers are not lockable unless the application specifies D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER when calling CreateDevice or Reset. Lockable back buffers incur a performance cost on some graphics hardware configurations.

What you should note from this is that you need to add D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER to your Present Parameters in **two** places:

1. The initial CreateDevice call, and,
2. Any Reset calls that may happen.

It is not sufficient to just add it to CreateDevice because **the original program may make a Reset call which may then overwrite your modified Present Parameters**.